# Do hotels offer "proof of stay" certificates to their guests?

Tags: hotels

I'm not sure what to call the document that I'm referring to, so I used the term "proof of stay."

I'm scheduled to travel to Latin America with a colleague of mine to attend a work-related conference. We're sponsored by our company, but our company is a research facility that receives grant money from the government. The government apparently requires us to provide "a document proving that X and Y stayed at the hotel for the duration of the conference with each of their names stated on it."

I've personally never heard of this before. I've contacted the hotel we're scheduled to stay at, and all they keep saying is that "yes, you can request an invoice when you leave." However, it's not exactly an invoice or billing statement we're looking for.

I'm just curious if anyone's heard of documents like these, and what we should be calling them or requesting on behalf of the hotel? I feel like many people traveling on their institution's dime may have faced this kind of situation and perhaps my unfamiliarity is also causing confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: Hotels don't keep track of who spend how much time where. You might want to see whether you can stop being the middleman and get your employer and hotel to talk to each other directly, or at least ask your employer exactly what term you should use.

Comment: IMO an invoice with your names on it should serve the purpose perfectly, wouldn't it? It would prove, that you stayed in the hotel.

Comment: @dunni Yes, if both of our names are on the invoice then I think that would serve the purpose. However, don't invoices usually only have the name of whoever's name is on the card that paid for the hotel? Is it possible to request another person's name to be added?

Comment: I just looked at a previous stay i had, and the invoice had both guest names on it. So while it might be only anecdotal experience, i still would say you can definitely request both names on the invoice (in my case they don't appear as recipient of the invoice, but just in a separate section with guest details)

Comment: Oh okay then this scenario is not completely unheard of. Thanks for the heads up, I guess it really depends on how I communicate with the hotel staff.

Comment: You can ask the hotel to add second person's name to the invoice. I've done this once and the hotel was nice enough to provide us two separate bills each for half the amount (It was a longer stay at an appartment hotel with rent split with a colleague).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I feel like many people traveling on their institution's dime may have faced this kind of situation and perhaps

I did travel on the government's dime occasionally and the hotel bill/invoice has always be acceptable.

The invoice includes

1. Name of guest
2. Arrival and departure dates

> However, it's not exactly an invoice or billing statement we're looking for.
> 3. List of all charges (including mini-bar and late night movies, if this is still a thing).

South American hotels also verify your identity when checking in which usually includes taking a photo of your passport.

> "a document proving that X and Y stayed at the hotel for the duration of the conference with each of their names stated on it."

That seems to meet all the requirements you stated. If not, your government needs to be clear about what exactly the want. If they need a single document juts staple the two invoices together.

> However, it's not exactly an invoice or billing statement we're looking for.

Why not? What specifically do you need that's not included in an Invoice?